Inverting numbering in number-formatted natbib bibliography
Assume a document called main.tex that contains two or more independent bibliographies (here: publ1 and publ2). Using option 'numbers' for natbib, the n publications contained within all bibliographies are numbered sequentially across the bibliographies in an increasing fashion (starting from [1] at the top to [n] at the bottom).

How do you receive a numbering in a decreasing fashion (with [1] at the bottom to [n] at the top)? That is, how can you invert the numbering while leaving the position of the references as they are?

MWE:
main.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bibtopic}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{is-unsrt}

\begin{document}

\section*{List of Publications}
This is a short list of references.

\begingroup

  \subsection*{In Review}
        \begin{btSect}{publ1}
        \btPrintNotCited
        \end{btSect}

  \subsection*{Published}
        \begin{btSect}{publ2}
        \btPrintNotCited
        \end{btSect}
\endgroup

\end{document}

publ1.bib:
@article{Foo1,
    title = {{Title 1}},
    volume = {1},
    journal = {Journal 1},
    author = {Author, A and Author, B},
    year = {2024},
    pages = {1--9}
}

publ2.bib:
@article{Foo2,
    title = {{Title 2}},
    volume = {2},
    journal = {Journal 2},
    author = {Author, A and Author, B},
    year = {2023},
    pages = {10--19}
}

@article{Foo3,
    title = {{Title 3}},
    volume = {3},
    journal = {Journal 3},
    author = {Author, A and Author, B},
    year = {2022},
    pages = {20--29}
}

Compilation:
pdflatex main
bibtex main1
bibtex main2
pdflatex main
pdflatex main


Just to be clear: Do you want title 2 to appear after title 3 or for the order to stay the same and just have the numering inverted?

@schtandard The order of the references shall stay the same, merely the numbering shall be inverted.

I couldn't reproduce you MWE. try this: \renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{\numexpr 50-#1\relax} where 50 is the total number of references.

@C.F.G Adding the line you suggest results in the following error: ! You can't use '\numexpr' in restricted horizontal mode.  \bibnumfmt #1->\numexpr  50-#1\relax, both when adding it before \begin{document} or within \section*{List of Publications}.

Do you only need a bibliography of uncited references as in your MWE or do you also want to be able to cite them with the new number?

I'm sure there is a cleaner way, but this seems to work. The \renewcommand changes how the numering in the bibliography is displayed, the \patchcmd modifies the numering of citations.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{bibtopic}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{is-unsrt}

\makeatletter
  % Invert numbering in bibliography.
  \renewcommand*\bibnumfmt[1]{[\the\numexpr\bt@totalctr+1-#1]}
  % Invert numbering in citations.
  \patchcmd\NAT@wrout{#1}{\the\numexpr \bt@totalctr+1-#1}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{Foo1}
\cite{Foo3}

\section*{List of Publications}
This is a short list of references.

\subsection*{In Review}
\begin{btSect}{publ1}
  \btPrintAll
\end{btSect}

\subsection*{Published}
\begin{btSect}{publ2}
  \btPrintAll
\end{btSect}

\end{document}


Yes, your code works nicely! Thank you.
